# Why can't I access an administrative share on my local machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualbox, network-share, hosts

I'm working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) VirtualBox image that I've set up as a CI/deployment testing environment.  I've got VirtualBox set to use Internal-Only networking.  I've set up hosts file redirects for the names of my production machines/database:

```
127.0.0.1      webserv1
127.0.0.1      webserv2
127.0.0.1      dbserv1
etc.
```

And my deployment script will then attempt to deploy to each address in turn.

My problem is that when I try to hit `\\webserv1\d$\deployment-directory`, or even `\\webserv1\d$\`, I'm getting an authorization prompt and I'm denied access.  I'm running as administrator on the VirtualBox console; I can't get any more authorized.  I *can* hit `\\127.0.0.1\d$\deployment-directory`.

I've even disabled the network adapter to make sure I wasn't somehow hitting the real production boxes (and I verified that I can still hit localhost with the machine in that condition).

Any tips?

Comment: How are you running your script?  Is it like a DOS batch file, PowerShell, something else?

Comment: You are using _the_ Administrator account or an account that is an administrator? Only the former (or a full Domain Admin) works on W2K8\R2.

Comment: It's *the* Administrator account.  The fix was registry-based - I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being related to name resolution and permissions.  The details are found in this post:  http://forums.techarena.in/server-networking/1195474.htm

Basically there are several registry entries which must be created in order to enable this configuration - out of the box Windows does not support it.

---

Copy&Paste from the now defunct website (via [WebArchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106170757/http://forums.techarena.in/server-networking/1195474.htm)):

---

**Allowing other machines to use filesharing via the DNS Alias
(DisableStrictNameChecking)**

This change alone will allow other machines on the network to connect
to the machine using any arbitrary hostname. (However this change will
not allow a machine to connect to itself via a hostname, see
BackConnectionHostNames below).

- Edit the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet
  \Services\lanmanserver\parameters` and add a value
  `DisableStrictNameChecking` of type DWORD set to 1.

**Allowing server machine to use filesharing with itself via the DNS
Alias (BackConnectionHostNames)**

This change is necessary for a DNS alias to work with filesharing from
a machine to find itself. This creates the Local Security Authority
host names that can be referenced in an NTLM authentication request.

To do this, follow these steps for all the nodes on the client
computer:

1. To the registry subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM
   \CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`, add new Multi-String Value
   `BackConnectionHostNames`
2. In the Value data box, type the CNAME or the DNS alias, that is
   used for the local shares on the computer, and then click OK.
   *Note: Type each host name on a separate line.*

**Providing browse capabilities for multiple NetBIOS names
(OptionalNames)**

Allows ability to see the network alias in the network browse list.

1. Edit the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet
   \Services\lanmanserver\parameters` and add a value `OptionalNames` of
   type Multi-String
2. Add in a newline delimited list of names that should be
   registered under the NetBIOS browse entries
   *Names should match NetBIOS conventions (i.e. not FQDN,
   just hostname)*

**Register the Kerberos service principal names (SPNs) for other
Windows functions like Printing (setspn)**

NOTE: Should not need to do this for basic functions to work,
documented here for completeness. We had one situation in which the
DNS alias was not working because there was an old SPN record
interfering, so if other steps aren't working check if there are any
stray SPN records.

You must register the Kerberos service principal names (SPNs), the
host name, and the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) for all the new
DNS alias (CNAME) records. If you do not do this, a Kerberos ticket
request for a DNS alias (CNAME) record may fail and return the error
code KDC_ERR_S_SPRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN.

To view the Kerberos SPNs for the new DNS alias records, use the
Setspn command-line tool (setspn.exe). The Setspn tool is included in
Windows Server 2003 Support Tools. You can install Windows Server 2003
Support Tools from the Support\Tools folder of the Windows Server 2003
startup disk.

How to use the tool to list all records for a computername:

```
setspn -L computername
```

To register the SPN for the DNS alias (CNAME) records, use the Setspn
tool with the following syntax:

```
setspn -A host/your_ALIAS_name computername
setspn -A host/your_ALIAS_name.company.com computername
```

Comment: It's OK to mark this Accepted. It lets people know that this problem has been solved.

Comment: +1. Good catch. This is a fairly common occurrence. It wasn't evident in your question that this was the problem you were running in to, but after reading your solution and re-reading your question the light bulb went on. ;)

Comment: I'll mark it accepted when it lets me - there's a 2-day waiting period for self-answers.